# What does CPU usage - 30% of 8 CPUs, 1 GPU mean?

Tags: performance, google-cloud-platform, cpu-usage

I have a VM instance created on GCP with 8 CPUs, 1 GPU(Nvidia Tesla). Now, when I ran a task (training Mozilla's Deepspeech model for custom language), I saw that the program consumed only 30% CPU(on GCP monitoring page). Now, I'd like to decrease the number of CPUs because future tasks will be of the same computational order as the initial one(I mean, why waste resources unnecessarily?). To what number should I decrease my CPUs count to? Is it 30% of 8 OR should I re-run the task to see if CPU % is because of a single CPU or multiple? OR How do I know my GPU is being utilized at all?

I can add other system specs(RAM etc..) here but I believe those things are independent of the scenario of my question.

Comment: It depend on your application. what kind of program do you run? Try to give more information.

Comment: I'm training Mozilla's Deepspeech engine. What more info do you need?

Answer (score 0):

As I know if you want to use GPU will install CUDA, and GPU loading and CPU loading are totally different. I see Mozilla's Deepspeech is based on tensorflow ,so you can try this document [using gpu](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu)

> > On a typical system, there are multiple computing devices. In TensorFlow, the supported device types are CPU and GPU. They are represented as strings. For example:
> >
> > - "/cpu:0": The CPU of your machine.
> > - "/device:GPU:0": The GPU of your machine, if you have one.
> > - "/device:GPU:1": The second GPU of your machine, etc.
> >
> > If a TensorFlow operation has both CPU and GPU implementations, the GPU devices will be given priority when the operation is assigned to a device. For example, matmul has both CPU and GPU kernels. On a system with devices cpu:0 and gpu:0, gpu:0 will be selected to run matmul.